# Can I report downvoting abuse here?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, abuse

I've asked a question:
[PHP performance: if vs. assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113739/php-performance-if-vs-assignment)

No matter if the question is bad, someone keeps down voting answers w/o leaving a comment to explain why. It seems to be just someone with a "bee in their bonnet" or running some other kind of scheme. I seem to remember people schooling the system in the past. I wondered if this is one of those cases. So I thought maybe someone can take a look at it.

Is this the correct way to handle such cases?

Comment: I knew this guy was up to something. Now he's had his account suspended: http://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/col-shrapnel For what reason I know not, but he has cast so many down votes.

Answer (score 6):

Downvoting is at every user's discretion, and comments are optional. There's nothing you can do really, except (as you did) add a comment saying that you think the downvote is unjustified, and asking for a reason why.

Comment: Moderators have the power to investigate. When something seems fishy, is there a way to go about having it looked into?

Comment: @sims what's to investigate? Somebody downvoted most answers. That's not forbidden.

Comment: Perhaps no one is gaming the system, but only a mod may be able to see that. This is my question, not particularly the down votes. If there is no way to game the system that's fantastic, but I've heard of such things in the past.

Comment: @sims there is only one downvote on each downvoted answer, so there is just one user involved. That practice is not forbidden, even if you have written an answer to the question yourself (as there is the conceivable case of every other answer being wrong.)

Comment: Cool. No worries then I guess.

Answer (score 1):

One work-around is

- don't answer your own question unless it's really answered the question.

I am seeing spam flags on the flag list, but those are irrelevant IMHO, so it could be misunderstood revenge downvotes.

Comment: I don't really care about my down votes. All the other answers were down voted repeatedly.